# lcurl installation no root

Tags: linux, permissions, curl, make

I have been trying to install a software for a full day now. After installing `htslib`/`bzip` and all dependencies locally (as I don't have root permissions), I am stuck at this error:

```
g++ -O3 -o angsd *.o /home/a1757330/src/htslib/libhts.a -lz -lm -lbz2 -llzma -lpthread -lcurl
/apps/software/binutils/2.26-GCCcore-5.4.0/bin/ld.gold: error: cannot find -lcurl
```

I tried to install `curl-7.73.0.tar` and then `curl_7.72.0.orig.tar` (which is the `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, and apparently `lcurl` was part of it but still doesn't work).

I downloaded the tar file, `untar`, `./confige`, `make`, `make install` but when I go back to my software, I still miss this dependency.

Do you have any ideas if I am doing something wrongly or did I forget something?

Comment: Where are the libraries that you built locally actually installed? `g++` will usually only search specific system directories by default - other search paths need to be added on the command line using `-L`

Comment: Here are the packages I installed locally (thanks to you I realise I dont use them all by default):
~/bin/autoconf
/usr/bin/curl
/apps/software/bzip2/1.0.6-foss-2016b/bin/bzip2
/usr/bin/xz

I also have "error: cannot find -lbz2"  "error: cannot find -llzma" "cannot find -lcurl" .. so many issues !